# converting a 3d matrix into feature vectors

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

So I have data in shape (100,100,5000).

Basically, it is a 100 by 100 pixel image which each (x,y) pixel having some spectrum vector..
So, the data is format

```
     [ [ [ 0, 0.2.....],[0.1,0.3.....].. and so on]]
```

When we do d[0][0][0] corresponds to (0,0) pixel in image and the spectrum value is 0

Now, i want to run kmeans algorithm in it.. Thats the background.

To run kmeans, I want to convert it into feature vector.. as

```
[0,0,0]
[0,0,0.2]
and so on..
```

Is there a "python" way to do this conversion. I am guessing there should be some numpy reshape method which can easily achieve this, rather than writing the three for loops which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Use numpy reshape http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html e.g.

```
a.reshape((m,n))
```

where `m` and `n`are the desired coordinates of your array `a`